# How to get specific class attribute

Tags: jquery, html

```
<a class="ab ac ad">HOME</a>
```

I need the second class attribute, something like this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
var a = $(this).attr("class").eq(1);
alert (a);
});
```

Any idea ?

Comment: For most use cases you should use `$(selector).hasClass(className)` instead.

Comment: `this.className.split[1]`

Comment: @Mr_Green, your solution doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a string, so you can just split it:

```
var a = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1];
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can split by space using:

```
echo $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1];
```